# Return a variables current scope (local, global, or static) for debugging script

Tags: php, debugging, scope

Is there a simple method to return a variables scope inside a function?

Is there something similar to gettype($var) that returns the scope?

Something like: getscope($var)?

(The closest I've been able to do is this script)

```
$full_var_array = get_defined_vars(); // way to much info here
$ignore_list = ['_GET','_POST','_COOKIE','_FILES','_SERVER','GLOBALS'];
$output= "";
foreach ($full_var_array as $k => $v){
    if (!in_array($k, $ignore_list)){
        $output.= $k ." = ".$v;
        if(!isset($GLOBALS[$k])){
            $output.= " - local only"; 
        }elseif($v!==$GLOBALS[$k]){
            $output.=  " - Global with same name exist with different value (".$GLOBALS[$k].")"; 
        }else{
            $output.=  " - Global with same name and value exist";      
        }
        $output.=  "<br/>";
    }
}

echo $output;
```

Far from perfect. Has to examine EVERY defined variable and still can't tell me 100% if a variable is global and can't devine static at all.

I've looked everywhere but only found others frustrated with the same issue.
Thank you.

Comment: I can't understand why you even need this, seems like a bad code smell if your code is dependent on knowing where/how a variable is defined in this way

Comment: You are correct. Finding bad code is exactly why I need it. I am writing a simple debugging script which outputs pertinent info. One common programing error is improper scope. Thinking you changed a global variable with a local variable of the same name, for example.

Comment: Have you looked at existing debugging tools such as xdebug?

Comment: No, and I will, thanks. But I really want to do this script from scratch. First as a learning experience. Second, I have some pretty specific goals. A very light, easily portable, pure php/mysql script. It must be activated by either a settings page for local debugging, or by an admin to troubleshoot a remote users activity without being viewable by the user. And it should be usable on the deep web which means highly secure, no javascript and very trim because the deep web is soooo sloooooowwww. Lastly, I'm having fun...

Comment: xdebug causes HUGE performance hit so one may need debugging code such as this for logging extra data in case of weird issues in production. xdebug is probably a better solution for single developer environment or test server.